# log-in problem as a user and guest session

Tags: login

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on VMware platform. No problem has shown up during the installation process.
But when I enter the password to log into Ubuntu it is making a beep sound and returning to login page again.
If I enter the wrong password then, it's showing that the password is wrong but when entering the right one the problem occurs.

What should i do ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
Press Ctrl+Alt+F6, type your username and password and enter this command:

`sudo chown <username>:<username> .ICEauthority`

Assuming `<username>` as your username.

Then switch back to GUI by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 and try to login again.